# Pass a templatized type to a member function in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a member function that can instantiate an object of a custom type (templatized), initializing its `const&` member to a local object of the function.
This is consistent since the lifetime of the custom type object is the same as the local_object.

The objective is caching some metadata of the local object because they don't change during its lifetime. The `operator()` (or any member function) computes some values, then used later in `func`, and the objective is offering a hook to change the behaviour of `func`.

Please no polymorphic solutions (currently used) due to (profiled) slowness.

This is a M(N)WE:

```
#include <vector>

class cls {
public:
    template <typename Custom> int func() {
        std::vector<int> local_object{0, 14, 32};
        Custom c(local_object, 42);
        return c();
    }
};

template<typename AType> class One {
public:
    One(const AType& obj, const int n): objref(obj), param(n), member_that_should_depend_on_objref(obj.size()) {}
    int operator()() { return 42; }
private:
    const AType& objref;
    const int param;
    float member_that_should_depend_on_objref;
};

template<typename AType> class Two {
public:
    Two(const AType& obj, const int n): objref(obj), param(n), other_member_that_should_depend_on_objref(obj.empty()), other_dependent_member(obj.back()) {}
    int operator()() { return 24; }
private:
    const AType& objref;
    const int param;
    bool other_member_that_should_depend_on_objref;
    int other_dependent_member;
};

int main() {
    cls myobj;
    auto a = myobj.func<One>();
    auto b = (myobj.func<Two>)();
}
```

G++ 5.3.0 says

```
tmp.cpp: In function 'int main()':
tmp.cpp:34:30: error: no matching function for call to 'cls::func()'
     auto a = myobj.func<One>();
                              ^
tmp.cpp:4:36: note: candidate: template<class Custom> int cls::func()
     template <typename Custom> int func() {
                                    ^
tmp.cpp:4:36: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tmp.cpp:35:32: error: no matching function for call to 'cls::func()'
     auto b = (myobj.func<Two>)();
                                ^
tmp.cpp:4:36: note: candidate: template<class Custom> int cls::func()
     template <typename Custom> int func() {
                                    ^
tmp.cpp:4:36: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Clang++ 3.7.1 says:

```
tmp.cpp:34:20: error: no matching member function for call to 'func'
    auto a = myobj.func<One>();
             ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:4:36: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template
      parameter 'Custom'
    template <typename Custom> int func() {
                                   ^
tmp.cpp:35:21: error: no matching member function for call to 'func'
    auto b = (myobj.func<Two>)();
             ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:4:36: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template
      parameter 'Custom'
    template <typename Custom> int func() {
                                   ^
2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto a = myobj.func<One>();
```

is wrong since `One` is a class template, not a class. Use

```
auto a = myobj.func<One<SomeType>>();
```

It's not clear from your code what `SomeType` should be.

**Update**

If you want to use:

```
auto a = myobj.func<One>();
```

you need to change `func` to use a template template parameter:

```
class cls {
public:
    template <template <class> class Custom > int func() {
        std::vector<int> local_object{0, 14, 32};
        Custom<std::vector<int>> c(local_object, 42);
        return c();
    }
};
```

Perhaps that was your intention.

Comment: `SomeType` should be deduced from the type of `local_object`. In the example case should be deduced as `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @Astrinus, type can be deduced from function templates only if there are arguments. When a function template does not have any arguments, the type has to be explicitly specified.